# How to initialize an array of structs without writing any data into it?

Tags: arrays, struct, rust

Can I  initialize an array of structs so that I can use it but without initializing the data at the allocated memory with any default or custom initializer? The reason I want to do this is mainly performance.

I don't care if the memory is just garbage, I can guarantee that whenever I need to access a variable of this array the values will be defined.

Maybe I can split this question into two smaller ones:

1. How can I initialize a struct instance without changing the data at the allocated memory?
2. How can I initialize an array without changing the data at the allocated memory?

The code that I would like to write:

```
struct AbcStruct {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
    pub c: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: [AbcStruct; 128];
    println!("{}", a[3].a);
}
```

In C++ I would do this:

```cpp
struct AbcStruct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

int main()
{
  AbcStruct a[128];
  std::cout << a[0].b << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *The reason I want to do this is mainly performance* — please benchmark your code before resorting to unsafe. *I can guarantee that whenever I need to access a variable of this array the values will be defined* — your demonstration code doesn't even do this correctly; you read `a[3].a` before defining it.